# How to align the contents in pages using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a pdf generator feature implemented in vuejs as frontend. My pdf structure is just like below

```
Heading


Section A

Title 1

description

Title 2

description


Section B

Title 1

description

Title 2

description
```

In the above example, Sections and Titles are dynamic data which user adds. So when contents exceeds to 2 pages sometimes the half of the description jump to next page, i wanted the title and description come together in next page if the description exceeds.

For example

page 1

```
Heading

Section A

1. Title 1

description

2. Title 2

description


Section B

1. Title 1

description

2. Title 2

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
```

page 2

```
unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

I wanted this title 2 and all it's description to display in the second page by removing them from page 1 as shown below.

page 2

```
2. Title 2

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

How can i achieve this?
My generate pdf code is give below (Margins are already implemented).

```
const generatePDF = async(pdfname?:any) =>{
    try{
      window.html2canvas = html2canvas;
      let content = document.getElementById('printSection');
       html2canvas(content, {
        useCORS: true,
        scale:2
      }).then(canvas => {
            const image = { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 };
            const margin = [0.5, 0.5];
            var imgWidth = 8.5;
            var pageHeight = 11;
      
            var innerPageWidth = imgWidth - margin[0] * 2;
            var innerPageHeight = pageHeight - margin[1] * 2;
      
            // Calculate the number of pages.
            var pxFullHeight = canvas.height;
            var pxPageHeight = Math.floor(canvas.width * (pageHeight / imgWidth));
            var nPages = Math.ceil(pxFullHeight / pxPageHeight);
      
            // Define pageHeight separately so it can be trimmed on the final page.
            var pageHeight = innerPageHeight;
            // Create a one-page canvas to split up the full image.
            var pageCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var pageCtx = pageCanvas.getContext('2d');
            pageCanvas.width = canvas.width;
            pageCanvas.height = pxPageHeight;
      
            // Initialize the PDF.
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'in', [8.5, 11]);
      
            for (var page = 0; page < nPages; page++) {
              // Trim the final page to reduce file size.
              if (page === nPages - 1 && pxFullHeight % pxPageHeight !== 0) {
                pageCanvas.height = pxFullHeight % pxPageHeight;
                pageHeight = ((pageCanvas.height * innerPageWidth) / pageCanvas.width) ;
              }
              // Display the page.
              var w = pageCanvas.width;
              var h = pageCanvas.height;
              console.log(w,h,'cnvas')
              pageCtx.fillStyle = 'white';
              pageCtx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
              pageCtx.drawImage(canvas, 0, page * pxPageHeight, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
      
              // Add the page to the PDF.
              if (page > 0) pdf.addPage();
              
              var imgData = pageCanvas.toDataURL('image/' + image.type, image.quality);
              console.log( margin[1], margin[0],pageHeight)
              pdf.addImage(imgData, image.type, margin[1], margin[0], innerPageWidth, pageHeight);
            }
      
            pdf.save(pdfname + '.pdf');   
          });
    }catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during PDF generation:', error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried page break, but since its is creating canvas, page break doesn't have any effect on them. Is there any alternative way ?